# How to show contact related to an Account in community?

Tags: account, permissions, sharing, contact, community

We have a community user say "U1" which is having a internal contact say "C1" in salesforce and that contact is related to an Account say "A1".
So when user "U1" login into the community and go to contacts tab we have to show only the contacts related to account "A1". i.e The community user can only be able to see the Account contacts with which its internal contact is related to.

Comment: What is the OWD for Accounts and Contacts in your system?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the `Sharing Set` on the Communities. If you go to `Setup--> Customize --> Communities --> Communities Settings`, you will find the section called `Sharing Sets`. Create a new sharing set with name and add the relevant profiles. Then add Account and Contacts to your available objects list. Then, below select object, you can find the section to configure access to these objects. Click on Setup besides Accounts first. Set the rule as shown below.
[image]

Then click on Setup besides Contacts and set the rule as shown below.
[image]

Other related pics are as follows:
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For Customer Community user, you can use [Sharing Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to share the Contact records.

Note to make your OWD as private for Account and Contacts.
Access might something like as follows:

[image]